# loading one model multiple times to the scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

im loading one model hundreds of times like this:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load(model, load_func);
```

and load_func is doing this:

```
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) );
scene.add( mesh );
```

i wonder if this is correct way to load model multiple times into the scene, maybe I should create mesh only once and then add it to scene multiple times on different location?

also I wonder if this is heavy on the network trafic, if model is on the server, does loader.load downloads it 100 of times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah that's not the right way. You should do something like this:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load(model, load_func);
function load_func(){
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) );
  for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    var mesh_new = mesh.clone();
    // Set position here!
    scene.add( mesh_new );
  }
}
```

Comment: so my code will also download model 100 times, and your won't ?